# how to handle 1 value returned from sql in php

Tags: php, sql

`$query = "SELECT val FROM table WHERE id = 1";
mysql_query($query);`

This returns a single peice of data from the database.
all the ways I know how to deal with this data are mysql_fetch_array() and mysql_fetch_assoc() is there a way to deal with 1 peice of data that doesn't involve pulling it into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`mysql_fetch_field`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php) which appears to do what you want.

```
mysql_fetch_field(0,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many wrapper libraries offer this, for example, with [ADODb](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm), it's simple

```
$value=$db->GetOne("select val from table where id=1");
```

It's not hard to roll your own either.

Comment: I tried doing this, //returns the last updated id $val = $DB->GetOne("SELECT id FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1"); But it doesn't work unless I do $DB->GetRow(). So, does this mean that I need to have where clause for the GetOne() to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mysql_result()`](http://php.net/mysql_result) like this;

```
mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0, 0);
```

The second parameter selects the row, and the third is the field number.